# Change link of Wordpress menu item for posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a menu that is used throughout the entire site (pages and posts). I would like to change the link of one single menu item (custom link) if the menu is displayed on on a blog post.
I tried using the plugin *Conditional Menus* which could do the job, but has the disadvantage that I would need to recreate the entire menu for each language and repeat this everytime the menu is updated.

I think it would be smarter to do this through php. I found this to check post vs. page:

```
<?php
    
  if(get_post_type() === 'post') {
       // Do something
  }    
  
?>
```

Would it be possible to set the `href` of the `<a>` tag in `menu-item-123` within this if-statement? Also, is there a way I can add this to functions.php in the child theme or does it need to placed somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: WordPress menus are usually rendered using the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class (or one that has inherited from that one, and modified specific methods), so you best bet is probably to handle this via the [`nav_menu_item_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_item_args/) filter, which this class applies before rendering the items.

Comment: You can do so using WordPress filter (wp_nav_menu_items), You can then add the conditions you want and return the final output of the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write following codes in your functions.php file Here ".primary-menu" WILL BE the css class of your menu  UL, I've setup 3rd child in the menu item, you can change it accordingly.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_link' );
    function change_link(){
        if(get_post_type() === 'post') { ?>
            <script>
                (function($) {
                    jQuery('.primary-menu li:nth-child(3) a').attr("href", "https://google.com");

                })(jQuery);
            </script>

<?php   }    

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! And sorry for the late reply!